# Return excerpt on Search

Tags: search, excerpt

Wondering how to return only excerpts on a search.

```
function get_the_excerpt( $deprecated = '' ) {
    if ( !empty( $deprecated ) )
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '2.3' );

    $post = get_post();
    if ( empty( $post ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        return __( 'There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.' );
    }

    /**
     * Filter the retrieved post excerpt.
     *
     * @since 1.2.0
     *
     * @param string $post_excerpt The post excerpt.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );
}
```

Do I just put this function within the Search loop?

Comment: Where are you using the excerpt? Can you show your code to give context to the proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

you will just do the `the_excerpt();`   in search loop

like this

Following is the code that goes in search.php

```
<?php if(have_posts()):while (have_posts()):the_post();?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <h3 class="title-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php the_excerpt(); ?>          
    </a>    
<?php
    endwhile;
    else:"No matching result found";
    endif;
?>
```